Are ships owned by a Rogue Trader benefit from Warrant Of Trade even if Rogue Trader is not on them?
To clarify let us assume a Rogue Trader reached 90 profit factor and decided to use their resources to procure a second ship(Or maybe they defeated a ship in battle, pulled it to a dock and got it repaired.) They gave the control of the ship to one of their dynasts, would the dynast in question benefit from Rogue Trader immunities/privileges?

Yes.
There is no actual requirement that a rogue trader personally be on a particular ship owned by their dynasty in order for that ship to benefit from the privileges granted by their warrant of trade.
In fact, it is entirely normal for a rogue trader to own multiple ships. The "Trappings of Power" section on page 329 explicitly states that rogue traders are often granted command over an entire fleet as part of being granted their Warrant of Trade - and the same page also mentions that a would-be-rogue-trader could potentially own at least one ship even before being granted a warrant of trade, presumably due to a background as a naval captain, noble, or less-privileged flavour of merchant.
That being said, the rules all seem to be written on the assumption that the rogue trader's party only has one ship with them most of the time. Presumably, the other ships owned by a trader's dynasty are assumed to be elsewhere in the universe, helping maintain the trader's profit factor.
